# Qué sigifica la frase 'Dicen que solo se está de más'?

Tags: música

Lo he oído en una canción. No entiendo qué significa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`estar de más` quiere decir que sobra.

algunas frases equivalentes, pero menos poéticas pueden ser:

- Dicen que solo se sobra
- Dicen que solo sobra uno

¿En que canción la escuchaste?

Comment: Dicen por OBK. Es igual que estarse de más?

Comment: Dicen muy claro a quien pisar. 
Pies de puntillas no pienso andar. 
Dicen que solo se está de más. 

Todavía no entiendo su significado. Puedes explicármelo?

Comment: No se a que te refieres con estarse de más.

Si reescribes la letra para quitarle ambigüedad podría quedar algo asi

Dicen muy claro a quien pisar
No pienso andar de puntillas
Dicen que sobro si estoy solo

Aún así, no trates de tomar la letra literalmente, seguramente se buscó la rima antes que un significado completamente coherente.